# Template type could not be deduced

Tags: c++, templates

I got a (simplified) function Foo

```
template<typename It, typename T>
void Foo(It begin, It end, T&& CallBar)
{
    CallBar(begin, end);
}
```

And another simplified function Bar

```
template<typename It>
It Bar(It begin, It end)
{
    return begin;
}
```

When I call both functions in the following way

```
std::vector<int> v{ 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6 };
Foo(v.begin(), v.end(), Bar);
```

I get the error

> 'declaration' : could not deduce template argument for 'identifier'

What else do I have to specify to make it compile?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Its a bit difficult in this case, since I am using the Test facilites of VS2017 to run the last code snippet.

Comment: You can use generalized lambdas to avoid having to specify the template argument in `Bar` : `Foo(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto begin, auto end) {return begin;});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that since `Bar` is a function template, it does not know which `Bar` you want.  You have to tell it what version of `Bar` to use.  One way to do that is by specifying the template type.  You can do that like:

```
Foo(v.begin(), v.end(), Bar<decltype(v.begin())>);
```

If you would like to not have to specify the template type, which to be honest, is a little brittle then we can wrap the call to `Bar` in a lambda.  This will allow the compiler to do all of the type deduction for us which is a lot easier to maintain.  For example if you change the iterator type nothing you neede to be changed unlie the previous solution.  Thanks to [0x499602D2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) that would be

```
Foo(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto b,auto e){return Bar(b,e);})
```

Comment: You can also use a lambda: `Foo(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto b,auto e){return Bar(b,e);})`

Comment: @0x499602D2 If you don't mind I would like to add that to the answer.

Comment: Sure go ahead. :)

Comment: I posted a similar comment at the same second as the updated answer :). It's still more simple to use a simple lambda than to embed `Bar` call inside a lambda. Also, compiler support for generalized lambdas must be checked (since this is a c++14 feature).

Comment: Couldn't struct `Bar` with `operator()` template also do the trick?

Comment: @W.F. Yes you could turn `Bar` into a functor.

Answer (score 2):

> What else do I have to specify to make it compile?

By example

```
template<typename It>
void Foo(It begin, It end, It(* CallBar)(It, It))
{
    CallBar(begin, end);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [template templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) to help solve this. As far as I know, it requires you to wrap your `Bar` function in a functor. By placing the functor template parameter first, you can specify it and let the iterator type be deduced.

```
#include <vector>

// T is a type that takes a 'class' template argument
template<template<class> class T, class It>
void Foo(It begin, It end)
{
    T<It>()(begin, end);
}

template<typename It>
struct Bar
{
    It operator()(It begin, It end)
    {
        return begin;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 8, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 6 };
    Foo<Bar>(v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```